# Google Play Console: "You have not completed a government apps declaration."

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am submitting an update of my app on Google Play Console.

I get the following message:

> You have not completed a government apps declaration.

[image: warning]

What does that mean and what should I do?

Comment: FYI, this kind of question is considered off-topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 90):

You just need to fill out a form under "Policy" > "App content" for that app. It's just 1 question. If it's not done yet, it will be at the top of the list on that page.

Comment: Someone else experiencing the issue that the form is not listed on the App content page?

Comment: Weird.  We get the same warning, but under "Policy" > "App content" everything is green and "ticked" - as it has been for many months.  There is no "Goverment Apps" section.

Comment: So bad that Google can't provide a link to that page or simply a description on how to fix the warning, in the warning text. The Google Play Console has become some insanely obtuse and complicated over the years.

Answer (score 49):

- Search in Play Console: "App content" сhoose it
- Refresh the page

Don't know why but at first it was all green, but after the "refresh page" the Government section appeared at the top of the list.

Comment: Your right, a hard refresh fixed it.  Ugh

Comment: I uploaded a build to `Internal testing` and looked in App Content again and now it was there - maybe that was like a hard refresh who knows 

Comment: Your answer of clicking 'App Content' from the start worked over the accepted answer for me. Clicking 'Policy Status' got me nowhere.

Comment: The "App content" button currently sits under `Policy and programs` in the console's main side panel. The section loaded is the same place where you declare other things like your Privacy policy link, use of ads, content ratings, etc. This `Government apps` declaration is a relatively new one Google added to the list, so perhaps your browser had some old version of the play console cached at the time, necessitating a refresh.

Answer (score 10):

- Go to App Content
- Refresh The page
- The Government Apps option would pop up right at the top of the list:

[image]

Comment: Hi . Do you have a template or an example of the submitted form " government apps proof of permission" that you have uploaded to google ? Please share a template with us

Comment: @Houcine Did you find any document for the same? If Yes please upload it here.

Comment: @srsstyle : Not yet brother, I've just ignored the google play request for now. If I find a template document I will share it with you here.